# ARCore: How do i inflate a layout to the AR view

Tags: android, android-layout, arcore, sceneform

How do I inflate the layout to an AR view, I have the anchor ID and I want the layout to be floating in the anchor.

`ViewRenderable.builder()
                    .setView(this, R.layout.render_view)
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(renderable -> viewRenderable = renderable);`

```
TransformableNode renderNode = new TransformableNode(surfaceView.getTransformationSystem());
                renderNode.setParent(anchor);
                renderNode.setRenderable(viewRenderable);
                renderNode.select();
```

But i have the surface View and it transformableNode requires TransformationSystem

Comment: try to use arFragment.getTransformationSystem()

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instantiate your own [TransformationSystem](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformationSystem):

```
SelectionVisualizer selectionVisualizer = new FootprintSelectionVisualizer();
transformationSystem = new TransformationSystem(this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(),
                                                        selectionVisualizer);
```